# Google Play Store version code conflict error when uploading new Android app version?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, google-play

I am trying to upload a new version of my Android app to the Google Play Store. The previous version had a **version code of 15 and app version in 2.1.12**, and I am attempting to release **version 2.1.13 with a version code of 16** in my app's build.gradle file. However, I'm encountering an error that says, `Version code 8 has already been used. Try another version code.`

```
android {

defaultConfig {
    compileSdk 34
    applicationId "com.google.www"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 16
    versionName "2.1.13"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
namespace 'com.google.www'
}
```

google play store version
[Google Play Store version code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEIXa.png)

Is there anything I should check or configure to resolve this version code conflict error? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I have confirmed that my app's build.gradle file specifies the correct version code of `16`, and there are no conflicting version codes in my project's libraries or modules. I have also cleared the cache and tried on different devices, but the issue persists.